# win32 console program side-by-side configuration error

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, console

A VC++ 2008 win32 console application uses some MFC functions, it can run without problem in 'Debug' mode within the VC++ 2008 environment. Also, the debug executable can ran on any computer with full version of visual studio 2008 installed.

But that same debug executable won't run on systems that don't have the visual studio 2008 installed, it gives the following error message:

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

The initial search for this problem leads to MSN recommendation to install the VC++ 2008 x86 redistributable SP1. But this failed to resolve the problem.

Then, the win32 console application is recompiled for 'Release' mode and it gives the following error message:

fatal error C1189:#error: Building MFC application with /MD[d](CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

this error happens in afx.h header.

I tried to actually #define _AFXDLL in preprocessor, but it created new errors about unable to convert MFC type of string to char* etc

I also tried 'Use of MFC' settings: in static library and shared DLL, both create more errors

The thing is, the original program was created in VC++ 6.0 and it used a lot of MFC functions (especially string and CObject), but after recompile in VC++ 2008 in a win32 console app, it somehow can work in debug mode, but can't be stand-alone exe in release mode, which is kinda what I need to have a stand-alone exe that can run on newer windows (7 or 8)

Could anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [Deploying Native Desktop Applications (Visual C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx), specifically [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx). This explains why you cannot run your application on systems that do not have Visual Studio installed. This does not address your second question: Your Release configuration doesn't build, because you have incompatible compiler/linker settings. This is a different question altogether and mandates a click on the *Ask Question* button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Don't build in Debug mode.  Build for Release.  You can't legally distribute the Debug DLLs.  You can build a Release version with Debugging information in it--via PDB files.

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if your release build has dependencies against some debug libraries, link against non debug ones.